# Checking whether the returned dict key leads to a list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have some Python code which returns two random keys from a dictionary.

```
key1,key2 = random.sample(stories.keys(), 2)
```

The thing is, the dictionary `stories` also contains list objects, and I want the variables `key1` and `key2` to just contain strings, not lists.

the `stories` dictionary contains a bunch of lists. But those lists *also* can contain lists. So it sort of looks like this:

```
{ "thing1": [
         "Some text",
         "Other text"
             ],
  "thing2": [
         "Some numbers",
         "How about those 2?"
             ],
  "thing3": {
         "Something else": [
                          "More stuff",
                          "Even more stuff"
                           ]
            },
  "thing4": [
            "Even more data",
            "Yep, more data"
            ]
   }
```

So how can I pick two keys among `thing1`, `thing2`, `thing3`, and `thing4`, yet not get `Something else`?

**Edit**: Just to clarify, I'm trying to select the keys which don't contain lists. So I would just like to choose among `thing1`, `thing2`, `thing4`, while leaving out `thing3`.

I've updated the data example to make things a bit clearer.

Comment: Your description is somewhat confused.  It's not possible for the code you posted to ever choose "Something else", as that's not a key of the `stories` dict itself.

Comment: Also, your dictionary `stories` contains only lists and and a dictionary, `key1` and `key2` can't contain strings since none of the dictionary values are strings.

Comment: Is your intent to ignore the keys that contain lists or is your intent to go join all the strings of the list together?  Please update your question to clarify these points rather than just replying in comments

Comment: @SamHartman Sorry, I should have been clearer.  Yeah, it was my intention to ignore the keys that contain lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the undesired entries like this:

```
dict((k,d[k]) for k in d if type(d[k]) == list and all(type(x) == str for x in d[k]))
```

or, better yet:

```
dict((k,d[k]) for k in d if isinstance(d[k],list) and all(isinstance(x,str) for x in d[k]))
```

Comment: I see a lot of cases where people are using `if type(obj) == SomeType` instead of `if isinstance(obj, SomeType)` lately. `isinstance` has the advantage of recognizing if `obj` is a subclass of `SomeType` where explicit comparing to `type(obj)` will not.  `isinstance` also accepts a collection of possible types in its 2nd arg, which would require more elaborate effort (using `all` or multiple conditions) with explicit testing.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire thanks, improved answer.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Yeah, I was thinking of using `isinstance()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, I think you just want single-level list, but not nested lists.

You can do a check when you generate the random key like this

```
if (stories[key][0] && isinstance(stories[key][0], list)):
  #get the next random key
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are picking keys from among the lists of strings that `thing1` and `thing2` point to? Maybe this will get you closer:

```
key_strings = (s for kv in stories.items() if isinstance(kv[1],list) for s in kv[1])
print(list(key_strings))
```

prints:

```
['Some numbers', 'How about those 2?', 'Some text', 'Other text']
```